# Why does QtConsole error out when I try to convert it to bundle in pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qtconsole, qtpy

My qtconsole code is this:

```
import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets

from qtconsole.rich_jupyter_widget import RichJupyterWidget
from qtconsole.manager import QtKernelManager

# The ID of an installed kernel, e.g. 'bash' or 'ir'.
USE_KERNEL = 'python3'

def make_jupyter_widget_with_kernel():
    """Start a kernel, connect to it, and create a RichJupyterWidget to use it
    """
    kernel_manager = QtKernelManager(kernel_name=USE_KERNEL)
    kernel_manager.start_kernel()

    kernel_client = kernel_manager.client()
    kernel_client.start_channels()

    jupyter_widget = RichJupyterWidget()
    jupyter_widget.kernel_manager = kernel_manager
    jupyter_widget.kernel_client = kernel_client
    return jupyter_widget

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """A window that contains a single Qt console."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.jupyter_widget = make_jupyter_widget_with_kernel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.jupyter_widget)

    def shutdown_kernel(self):
        print('Shutting down kernel...')
        self.jupyter_widget.kernel_client.stop_channels()
        self.jupyter_widget.kernel_manager.shutdown_kernel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(window.shutdown_kernel)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

it successfully compiles when I run it but when I click on the finished pyinstaller (`pyinstaller --onefile main.py` or `pyinstaller --windowed --onedir Yuro.py`) bundle, this qtconsole errors out with message:

```
File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 28, in __init__
  File "main.py", line 14, in make_jupyter_widget_with_kernel
  File "jupyter_client/utils.py", line 26, in wrapped
  File "jupyter_client/utils.py", line 23, in wrapped
  File "nest_asyncio.py", line 70, in run_until_complete
  File "asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result
  File "asyncio/tasks.py", line 256, in __step
  File "jupyter_client/manager.py", line 362, in _async_start_kernel
  File "jupyter_client/manager.py", line 347, in _async_start_kernel
  File "jupyter_client/utils.py", line 26, in wrapped
  File "jupyter_client/utils.py", line 23, in wrapped
  File "nest_asyncio.py", line 70, in run_until_complete
  File "asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result
  File "asyncio/tasks.py", line 256, in __step
  File "jupyter_client/manager.py", line 308, in _async_pre_start_kernel
  File "jupyter_client/manager.py", line 138, in kernel_spec
  File "jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 294, in get_kernel_spec
  File "jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 247, in _get_kernel_spec_by_name
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "ipykernel/kernelspec.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "ipykernel/debugger.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "debugpy/server/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "debugpy/_vendored/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/2n/h8v95wf976v7byjf7s78jfxh0000gn/T/_MEIu7ujzo/debugpy/_vendored'
```

I took this qtconsole code from the qtconsole github: "https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/blob/master/examples/embed_qtconsole.py." Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: seem a problem between debugpy and pyinstaller. check this issue  to see if it helps: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5363